# Created date timestamp of the C:\Windows\ folder is older than the "original install date" of the Windows 7 OS, why?

Tags: windows-7, windows, timestamp, forensics

Created date of my  C:\Windows\ folder in a Windows 7 machine is "‎14 ‎July ‎2009, ‏‎08:07:05", however, the "original install date" obtained from the "systeminfo" command in cmd is "27-6-2013, 11.33.15".

What may be the reason?

Also, many system files have create date older than the OS installation date. Need this explanation for an important assignment, please help.

Comment: "many system files have create date older than the OS installation date:" This is normal, system files unless they are updated via some windows update will have the original date stamp from Microsoft when they were created by Microsoft.

Comment: The create date won't change even because a fresh copy is made in the current machine? It does not happen to normal files, is it a speciality of system files? @Moab

Comment: System files will not change unless they were updated by Microsoft on the install media.

Comment: In other words system file creation date is when the file was created by Microsoft, not when they were created on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because a system file/folder's creation date is when the file was created by Microsoft, not when they were created on the hard drive.
Answered by @Moab in comments.